# Not writing to new xls sheet using Java

Tags: java, xls

I have a java app where it’s writing sql statement output from database to an excel file(xls)
So when it reaches a the limited number of row that xls has which is around 65000 then it writes to a new sheet.

This was done previously where it was able to write to second sheet, but when adding the new sheet(sheet4) it’s not working.

I’m using JXL library and error I’m getting is exceed maximum number of rows, so the two sheets are full but when adding the third it’s not writing to it

Below is the code.

rs5 is nothing but an sql statement.

```
WritableSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheet("ServiceSummary");
                WritableSheet sheet3 = workbook.getSheet("ServiceSummary2");
                WritableSheet sheet4 = workbook.getSheet("ServiceSummary3"); // added third sheet to handle more rows
 
                       
                     // Added sheet4 and if else statement to handle max row exception 65000
                        
                        System.out.println("number of rows in xls" + pos );
                       
                        
                        
                        if (pos > 130000)
                        {
                              System.out.println("third sheet for ServiceSummary3");
                               while(rs5.next()){
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(0,1+(counter), customerAccount, arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(1,1+(counter), rs5.getString(1), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(2,1+(counter), rs5.getString(2), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(3,1+(counter), rs5.getString(3), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(4,1+(counter), rs5.getString(4), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(5,1+(counter), rs5.getString(5), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(6,1+(counter), rs5.getString(6), arial10format));
                                     sheet4.addCell(new Label(7,1+(counter), rs5.getString(7), arial10format));
                                 try{sheet4.addCell(new Number(8,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(8)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet4.addCell(new Label(8,1+(counter), rs5.getString(8), arial10format));}
                                 try{sheet4.addCell(new Number(9,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(9)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet4.addCell(new Label(9,1+(counter), rs5.getString(9), arial10format));}
                                 try{sheet4.addCell(new Number(10,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(10)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet4.addCell(new Label(10,1+(counter), rs5.getString(10), arial10format));}
                                 counter ++;
                                 pos++;
                             }
                             
                        }
                       
                        else if (pos >= 65000)
                        {
                               
                               while(rs5.next()){
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(0,1+(counter), customerAccount, arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(1,1+(counter), rs5.getString(1), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(2,1+(counter), rs5.getString(2), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(3,1+(counter), rs5.getString(3), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(4,1+(counter), rs5.getString(4), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(5,1+(counter), rs5.getString(5), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(6,1+(counter), rs5.getString(6), arial10format));
                                 sheet3.addCell(new Label(7,1+(counter), rs5.getString(7), arial10format));
                                 try{sheet3.addCell(new Number(8,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(8)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet3.addCell(new Label(8,1+(counter), rs5.getString(8), arial10format));}
                                 try{sheet3.addCell(new Number(9,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(9)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet3.addCell(new Label(9,1+(counter), rs5.getString(9), arial10format));}
                                 try{sheet3.addCell(new Number(10,1+(counter), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(10)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet3.addCell(new Label(10,1+(counter), rs5.getString(10), arial10format));}
                                 counter ++;
                                 pos++;
                             }
                             
                        }
                       
                        else
                         
                        {
                        
                        while(rs5.next()){
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(0,1+(pos), customerAccount, arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(1,1+(pos), rs5.getString(1), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(2,1+(pos), rs5.getString(2), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(3,1+(pos), rs5.getString(3), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(4,1+(pos), rs5.getString(4), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(5,1+(pos), rs5.getString(5), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(6,1+(pos), rs5.getString(6), arial10format));
                            sheet2.addCell(new Label(7,1+(pos), rs5.getString(7), arial10format));
                            try{sheet2.addCell(new Number(8,1+(pos), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(8)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet2.addCell(new Label(8,1+(pos), rs5.getString(8), arial10format));}
                            try{sheet2.addCell(new Number(9,1+(pos), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(9)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet2.addCell(new Label(9,1+(pos), rs5.getString(9), arial10format));}
                            try{sheet2.addCell(new Number(10,1+(pos), Double.parseDouble(rs5.getString(10)), arial10format));}catch(Exception e){sheet2.addCell(new Label(10,1+(pos), rs5.getString(10), arial10format));}
                            pos++;
                        }}
                      
                        rs5.close();
                        rs5 = null;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please clarify "it’s not working". You should post any error message and the full stack trace. On which line exactly is the error?

Comment: Can you please improve your question by including the stack trace of the error that you are getting? Otherwise, there is no way you can be assisted with the information that you have provided.

Comment: I'd start out by replacing all `catch(Exception e)` with `catch(NumberFormatException e)` this may give you a better feedback on what is wrong

Comment: Have editied the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset counter to 0 when starting the 3rd sheet. As it is now sheet 3 will start on row 65000 and going down towards 65535

Comment: Will removing the counter from second sheet and keeping in third work? Or before entering the while loop for third sheet I should make the counter zero

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell from what you have shared so far.  You could try to put it in sheet 2 (i.e. inside `else if (pos >= 65000)` but outside/after the while loop: `if (pos > 130000) counter = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for that, it's writing to the new page now!